# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.renegotiatePending(J)I

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, https

```
2024-03-27 10:01:21.370 ERROR 13660 --- [nio-443-exec-10] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Error running socket processor

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.renegotiatePending(J)I
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.renegotiatePending(Native Method) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.getHandshakeStatus(OpenSSLEngine.java:1026) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.wrap(OpenSSLEngine.java:447) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeWrap(SecureNioChannel.java:460) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1616) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.du</groupId>
    <artifactId>common_maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Firefox Browser:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

**Is there any solution?**

Comment: Your question is a collection of error message s and configuration data, but what actually is missing is a question and a description of the set-up (programs versions, used OS...) and what you have tried to fix the problem.